# Requiring a Module With Alloy MVC

Tags: titanium-alloy

Right, so, if I was simply using Titanium, I could write:

```
var platino = require("co.lanica.platino");
```

And I'd be good to go. Since moving to Alloy, I don't know how to replicate the same line in the afforementioned MVC framework.

Do I add it under the global namespace? I already added the module in tiapp.xml, but I have no idea how to access it as a variable "platino".

The docs for Alloy are pretty sparse...any suggestions?

Comment: it's the same in Alloy...are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Require method is almost same in Alloy, you can use the require keyword in your js file and implement as in classic approach.

checkout the [docs.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Global-method-require)